# Achieving properties of binary and collation at the same time

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a varchar field in my database which i use for two significantly different things. In one scenario i use it for evaluating with case sensitivity to ensure no duplicates are inserted. To achieve this I've set the comparison to binary. However, I want to be able to search case-insensitively on the same column values. Is there any way I can do this without simply creating a redundant column with collation instead of binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t_search (value VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE UTF8_BIN PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT
INTO    t_search
VALUES  ('test');

INSERT
INTO    t_search
VALUES  ('TEST');

SELECT  *
FROM    t_search
WHERE   value = 'test' COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;
```

The second query will return both rows.

Note, however, that anything with `COLLATE` applied to it has the lowest coercibility.

This means that it's `value` that will be converted to `UTF8_GENERAL_CI` for the comparision purposes, not the other way round, which means that the index on `value` will not be used for searching and the condition in the query will be not sargable.

If you need good performance on case-insensitive searching, you should create an additional column with case-insensitive collation, index it and use in the searches.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the COLLATE statement to change the collation on a column in a query. see [this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collate.html) for extensive examples.